# How to validate WP_editor(product description box) in my website?

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, dokan

In my website i have a product description box, is coming from dokan plugin. I have front end product add form, In that form i have a WP_editor text area. I need to validate it. but i did some research and find some code to validate it but its not working.

[RESULT OF THE CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnJvS.png)

If I add the content of the description box its always show the  error message.

What I'm doing wrong?
please help me.
Thanks for your valuable time.

Here is the WP_editor Validate code in child theme/funtion.php

```
function dokan_can_add_product_validation_customized( $errors ) {

 $post_content= absint( sanitize_textarea_field( $postdata['post_content'] ) );

 if ( empty( $post_content) && ! in_array( 'Please des' , $errors ) ) {
      $errors[] = 'Please insert a description';
  }
  return $errors;
}
add_filter( 'dokan_can_add_product', 'dokan_can_add_product_validation_customized', 35, 1 );
add_filter( 'dokan_can_edit_product', 'dokan_can_add_product_validation_customized', 35, 1 );
function dokan_new_product_popup_validation_customized( $errors, $data ) {
 if ( ! $data['post_content'] ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'no-price', __( 'Please insert a description', 'dokan-lite' ) );
  }
}
add_filter( 'dokan_new_product_popup_args', 'dokan_new_product_popup_validation_customized', 35, 2 );
```

code of wp_editor -

```
<div class="dokan-form-group">
<label for="post_content" class="control-label"><?php esc_html_e( 'Description', 'dokan-lite' ) ?> 


 <i class="fa fa-question-circle tips" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Add your product description', 'dokan-lite' ) ?>"

 aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
<?php wp_editor( htmlspecialchars_decode( $post_content, ENT_QUOTES ), 'post_content', array('editor_height' => 50, 'quicktags' => false, 'media_buttons' => false, 'teeny' => true, 'editor_class' => 'post_content') ); ?>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i found a solutions,

after doing big research i found a method to validate WP_editor.

**Here is my code in child theme/funtion.php**

```
function dokan_can_add_product_validation_customized( $errors ) {



if (empty($_POST['post_content'])) { 
 
$errors[] = 'Please insert a Description '; 
}

 return $errors;
}
```

Thank you